# Proof for: Let A and B be sets s.t $ A \cap B = A $ iff $ A \subseteq B $

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I am practicing some proofs involving sets and I would like to see if what I did was a valid proof because it seemed to be different from the one provided in the textbook I am using given that it did not use a contrapositive proof.

Claim: Let A and B be sets s.t $ A \cap B = A $ iff $ A \subseteq B $

Let $P(A,B): A \cap B = A$ and $q(A,B):  A \subseteq B $

1) Show that $ \neg q(A,B) \implies \neg p(A,B)$

2) Show that $q(A,B) \implies p(A,B)$

Proof: [1] Assume $A \not\subseteq B$

Thus, without loss of generality, assume that $x \in A$ and $ x \not\in B $

According to $ q(A,B): A\cap B \subseteq A \:\: \mathrm{and}\:\: A \subseteq A \cap B$ because, $ x \in A \:\: \mathrm{and}\:\: x\not\in B \implies x \in (A-B) \implies x \not\in A \cap B $ and $ x \in A $. Hence, $ A \cap B \not\subseteq A$. Because, $ x \in A $ and $ x \not\in A\cap B$, then $ A \not\subseteq A \cap B $. Hence, $ A \cap B \neq A $

[2]: Assume $ A \subseteq B $.

Let $ x \in A \implies x \in B $ without loss of generality.

Because $ x \in A $ and $ x \in B $, then $ x \in A \cap B $
$ \implies $ As $ x \in A \cap B $ and $ x \in A $, then $ A \cap B \subseteq A $.
Since, $ x \in A $ and $ x \in A \cap B $, then $ A \subseteq A \cap B $. Thus, $ A \cap B = A $.

$\therefore A \cap B = A $ iff $ A \subseteq B $

Is what I did justified ? I would greatly appreciate any feedback or advice.

Thank you

Comment: A much simpler proof is to simply note that $ A \cap B \subseteq A $ by definition, and if $ x \in A $, then $ x \in B $ as $ A \subseteq B $, then as $ (x \in A \cap B) \leftrightarrow (x \in A \land x \in B) $ we have that $ x \in A \cap B $ so that $ A \subseteq A \cap B $. But yes, your proof is correct.

Comment: It ia not a good start to say let $A$ and $B$ be sets such that $A\cup B=A$ iff $A\subseteq B$. That says $A, B$ satisfy the property that you want to show holds for all sets.  There are also some mistakes, for example we cannot conclude that $A\cap B\not\subseteq A$.  The term without loss of generality is not used correctly. The proof is fixable, but needs rewriting.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will keep both in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is correct.

For the first part, or to be more precise, the first direction, you could also do with more direct way.

Suppose that $A\subseteq B$, therefore there is an element $x$ of $A$ which is in  $B$, thus $A\cap B\subseteq A$. But, $ A\subseteq A \cap B$. Therefore we have $A = A\cap B$.